# Unable to get response of google maps by php curl

Tags: php, google-maps, curl

Hi i am trying to get response of reverse geocoding google maps api by php curl. 
My code is

```
$url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.999,72.582&sensor=false&key=myAPIKey";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response1 = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response1);
    exit;
```

i am getting nothing.

Comment: Thanks for your API key... And if you'd bother actually hitting that url in a browser, you'd see a json response: "the provided api key is invalid"...

Comment: Yes i am getting the json data in browser

Comment: @MarcB Plz check my edit ...i am getting the data on above link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=22.999,72.582&sensor=false&key=myApiKey";
    $timeout = 60;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
?>
```

Since your trying to connect over https you need to tell curl that your trying to connect over https :P

Answer (score 0):

In my case, escaping the '&' character with `&amp;` in $url variable solved the issue.